# How to disable logging all messages in a Kafka batch in case of an exception?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When using `@KafkaListener` with batches, the error handler logs the content of the full batch (all messages) in case of an exception.

How can I make this less verbose? I'd like to avoid spamming the log files with all the messages and only see the actual exception.

Here is a minimal example of how my consumer currently looks like:

```kotlin
@Component
class TestConsumer {
    @Bean
    fun kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory(kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> {
        val configs = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties()
        configs[ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG] = 10000
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
        factory.consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(configs)
        factory.isBatchListener = true
        return factory
    }

    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["myTopic"],
        containerFactory = "kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    fun batchListen(values: List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>) {
        // Something that might throw an exception in rare cases.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?

This container property was added in 2.2.14.

```java
    /**
     * Set to false to log {@code record.toString()} in log messages instead
     * of {@code topic-partition@offset}.
     * @param onlyLogRecordMetadata false to log the entire record.
     * @since 2.2.14
     */
    public void setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(boolean onlyLogRecordMetadata) {
        this.onlyLogRecordMetadata = onlyLogRecordMetadata;
    }
```

It has been [true by default since version 2.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1659) (which is why the javadocs now read that way).

This was the previous javadoc:

```java
    /**
     * Set to true to only log {@code topic-partition@offset} in log messages instead
     * of {@code record.toString()}.
     * @param onlyLogRecordMetadata true to only log the topic/parrtition/offset.
     * @since 2.2.14
     */
```

Also, starting with version 2.5, you can set the log level on the error handler:

```java
    /**
     * Set the level at which the exception thrown by this handler is logged.
     * @param logLevel the level (default ERROR).
     */
    public void setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level logLevel) {
        Assert.notNull(logLevel, "'logLevel' cannot be null");
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Spring Boot version 2.5.1, so `onlyLogRecordMetadata` should already be `true` in my case, but it seems it is not. How can I access my `ConsumerProperties` to check/change this?

Comment: Autowire the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` then `registry.getListenerContainer(listenerId).getContainerProperties()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And yes, it already is true. I'll try to find out what is going on with the logs.

Comment: Ah, got it. For my minimal example, I copied `kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory` into my application code, which uses Spring/Kafka version `2.7.3`. Before that, I was calling a version of it from a self-created library, which is still on version `2.5.1`. That's why `isOnlyLogRecordMetadata` was `false` there and is `true` in my latest test. Thanks again, all makes sense now. :-)